# Read arrays from csv

Tags: python, pandas

Parsing a csv file with the content

```
time,X,Y,status1,status2
1659312306212,"[-53, -70]","[-1512, -1656]",-65,18.44140625
1659312421965,"[25, -34]","[-1532, -1520]",-71,18.43359375
```

using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("horrible.csv")
```

results in

```
print(df)
            time           X               Y  status1    status2
0  1659312306212  [-53, -70]  [-1512, -1656]  -65        18.441406
1  1659312421965   [25, -34]  [-1532, -1520]  -71        18.433594

print(df.dtypes)
time         int64
X           object
Y           object
status1      int64
status2    float64
dtype: object
```

What additional steps are necessary to

1. interpret the objects in the X and Y columns as an array of numbers

and

2. pivot them for each row

such that the resulting df looks like

```
           time    X     Y     status1   status2
0  1659312306212   -53   -1512  -65       18.441406
1                  -70   -1656  
2  1659312421965    25   -1532  -71       18.433594
3                  -34   -1520
```

?

Answer (score 1):

To interpret the objects in the X and Y columns as arrays of numbers and pivot them for each row, you can try this:

Convert the string representations of arrays in the X and Y columns to actual arrays using the ast.literal_eval() function from the ast module and create new columns for each element in the arrays.
Then Pivot the DataFrame to have each element in the arrays as a separate row.

You can try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("horrible.csv")

# Convert string representations of arrays to actual arrays
df['X'] = df['X'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['Y'] = df['Y'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Create new columns for each element in arrays
df = df.explode('X').explode('Y').reset_index(drop=True)

# Pivot the DataFrame
df = df.pivot(columns=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), values=['X', 'Y'])
df.columns = [f'{prefix}{index}' if prefix != '' else f'{col}{index}'
          for col, prefix, index in df.columns]

print(df)
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I get a "KeyError: 0" Exception executing df = df.pivot(columns=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), values=['X', 'Y'])

Comment: I actually asked chatGPT for that error, I updated the answer, maybe that code is working

Comment: Didn't help, the exception still occurs

Comment: Sorry, the I don't know either

Comment: I rolled back on the answer to the first code I send